# Access class' imported class

Tags: mysql, vb.net, class

I have a VB.Net program that uses MySQL connection.
To make the code cleaner and more reusable, I made a class `DBManager` with all my functions.
I made this class in a separate project and I'm planning to get a standalone DLL from this class in near future.
So for now my main program simply imports `DBManager`
One of the function in `DBManager` needs an argument of type `MySqlCommand`.

Of course I've imported `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` on top of DBManager, but now I can't access the type (or maybe better, the class) `MySqlCommand` from my main program.
A possible workaround is to import `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` on my main program, but I think that is not a clean solution because i import the entire MySql Namespace just for using `MySqlCommand` as argument....
Is there a cleaner method to get `MySqlCommand` class out of `DBManager` without importing `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` in the main program?

Comment: That's not a workaround.  It's the required solution.  If that method needs a parameter of that type then your application has to know that that type exists and the only way to do that is to reference to library in which that type is declared.  There's no way around that.  How about, instead of expecting a `MySqlCommand`, you write that method to expect a `String` containing SQL code and a `Dictionary` of parameter values and then construct the command object internally?  If you don't the consuming app to have to know about `MySqlClient` then don't expose any types from that namespace.

Comment: Hi, thaks you jmcilhinney, I've used a MySqlCommand type in order to use the method AddWithValue. I wonder if is possible to create a class that copy exactly what MySqlCommand do in order to use this custom class in place of MySqlCommand..... otherwise I will try to use a string

Comment: Just use `AddWithValue` inside your method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution based on jmcilhinney's suggestion.
I've made a class `DBSqlCommand` with two public variables:`Public CommandText As String` and `Public Parameters As SortedList(Of String, String)` that support the add method I need to insert parameters.
 then I've changed my method's argument type to `DBSqlCommand`.
Now when i call my method, it handles MySqlCommand internally and it translates the list to command parameters.